# Mdiparent and SplitContainer

Tags: c#, parent-child, mdichild, mdiparent, splitcontainer

I am using a `SplitContainter` in MDI parent Form.

My problem is I loaded a form in `panel1` named *First Form*. In this First Form with a button I load `SecondForm` in panel2.

I am using this code:

```
        Form In_but = new SecondForm();
        In_but.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
        In_but.TopLevel = false;
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(In_but);
        In_but.Show();
```

But it's not working. The error is: `does not contain definition splitContainer1`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'Not Working'? Are you getting an error, is it doing nothing, or doing something unexpected?

Comment: the error is does not contain defination splitContainer1

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code sample, I suspect your problem is when you refer to `this.splitContainer`, `this` is your 'First form' on panel 1, and your SplitContainer is on `this.ParentForm`.

I'd suggest changing that line to `this.(ParentForm as <whatever class your parent form is>).splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(In_but);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
frmChild frmChild = new frmChild();
        frmChild.TopLevel = false;
        frmChild.Parent = this.splitContainer3.Panel2;
        frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd.Show();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
frmTest fs = new frmTest();  //frmTest is the form that you going to call 

fs.MdiParent = this; //the main form is a mdiform and have a splitcontainer with 
                     //two panels

this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(fs); //add the fs form to the panel2

fs.Show(); //show the form
```

Comment: Why would changing the variable you're adding to a container somehow change the error `does not contain definition splitContainer1`